# Can't seem to get my navigation bar next to my logo

Tags: html, css

[Codes](https://jsfiddle.net/samiraqueen/hwpyrf3e/)

```css
body{ 
    margin: 0;
}

.logo {
    text-indent: -999999px;
    background: url('logo3.png');
    width: 216px;
    height: 219px;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #eef3f5;
    padding-top: 24px;
}
.headerContent {
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.headercontent a img{
    width: 659px;
    height: 144px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
.nav {
    height: 40px;
    background: #0000ff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: right;
}
.nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: black;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
}
.headerbreak {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0000; 
}
```

```html
  
<title> Grenada Down Syndrome Association</title>
    
    
    
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <div class="headerContent">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="logo3.png" alt="Grenada Down Syndrome Association"/>
        </a>
        
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerbreak"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really need some help with this guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make lots of changes in css.

First you have give long width of `.headerContent` decrease it or remove it make next to logo.

Then use `display:inline-block`.

Give following css:

```
.headerContent > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}


.nav {
    background: #0000ff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwpyrf3e/2/)**

Comment: You're answering questions that were not asked, ketan? By answering such low quality questions you are encouraging others like it, hence lowering the quality of SO. SO's mission is to make internet better, but not by providing free `web-design` or `fix-my-code` services. You should discourage such questions, not encourage them.

Comment: This is the question. "*Can't seem to get my navigation bar next to my logo"*

Comment: I know, that's why i will give them chance to learn how to post. As it is his/her first post.

Comment: Thank you ketan! That really helped but now its too high to the top margin, i'll try to get that part fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: @you can give top margin to `.header` and to fix use `position:fixed.` you should learn with css properly  first.

Comment: Thank you. And i definitely will.